# SSRS sharepoint ERROR: required SKUs: Express - actual SKU EnterpriseCore

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, sharepoint-2013

I need help concern this issues.
i have SQL 2012 Enterprise core and Sharepoint 2013 under same machine.
I installed the RS for sharepoint integration mode.
once i create the SQL reporting service application and click on system execution give me this error ( Windows SharePoint Services integration" is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services )
the log file as following:

1. INFO: Reporting Services starting SKU: Express
2. INFO: Catalog SQL Server Edition = EnterpriseCore
3. ERROR: required SKUs: Express  - actual SKU EnterpriseCore

but i am installing it from SQL enterprisecore media.
i uninstalled and re-installed and keep saying same message error.
Is there a solutions for that.
PS:i cannot remove my database instance

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a somewhat similar situation where Sharepoint 2013 was installed on SQL Express. And got this error. I moved my sharepoint 2013 installation to SQL Developer edition and still got the error. Reinstalled the SSRS but still no go.

Figured it finally out, in the reporting services config file

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\WebServices\Reporting\rsreportserver.config
```

there is a setting called InstanceId which was pointing to the Express edition Instance - I changed this to the developer edition InstanceId and restarted the Reporting Service inside Central Admin and then it worked.

You can find the InstanceIds in the registry as keys under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
```